# How to get All textview data from List View Custom Adapter on Button Click

Tags: android, listview

So, here is my code what I want to do is get all the data from listview custom adapter by clicking the button save. What I have here is I can delete a single data from the listview or I can delete it all by clicking the delete button. My problem is, I cannot get all data from the listview by clicking the save button and store on a string. [Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbGAT.png)

ReviewYourOrder.java

```
package com.example.orderingsystem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
.....

public class ReviewYourOrder extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();

DatabaseAdapter ourDatabase;
Typeface customFont;
TextView review_you_order_txt,review_your_order_quantity,review_your_order_description,review_your_order_price;
Button save,cancel;
ListView myList;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reviewyourorder);

    customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/EraserRegular.ttf");

    review_you_order_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.review_your_order_tv);
    review_you_order_txt.setTypeface(customFont);

    review_your_order_quantity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.review_your_order_quantity_tv);
    review_your_order_quantity.setTypeface(customFont);

    review_your_order_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.review_your_order_description_tv);
    review_your_order_description.setTypeface(customFont);

    review_your_order_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.review_your_order_price_tv);
    review_your_order_price.setTypeface(customFont);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setTypeface(customFont);

    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setTypeface(customFont);

    openDB();
    ourDatabase.open();
    final Cursor c = ourDatabase.getAllDataReviewYourOrder();
    String[] ReviewYourOrderNames = new String[] {DatabaseAdapter.KEY_REVIEWYOURORDER_TABLENUMBER,DatabaseAdapter.KEY_REVIEWYOURORDER_DESC,DatabaseAdapter.KEY_REVIEWYOURORDER_PRICE,DatabaseAdapter.KEY_REVIEWYOURORDER_QUANTITY};
    int[] ReviewYourOrderID = new int[] {R.id.tablenumber,R.id.itemdesc,R.id.itemprice,R.id.itemquantity};
    final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.reviewyourorder_items, c, ReviewYourOrderNames, ReviewYourOrderID,0);
    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.review_your_order_listview);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id_o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReviewYourOrder.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove this Order?");
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ourDatabase.open();
                    ourDatabase.deleteReviewYourOrder(id_o);
                    myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }});
            adb.show();
          }
    });
}

private void openDB() {
    ourDatabase = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    ourDatabase.open();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.save_button:
        String sample;
        sample = "asd";
            addOrder(sample.toString(),sample.toString(),sample.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.cancel_button:
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReviewYourOrder.this);
        dialog.setTitle("CANCEL ORDER?");
        dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Cancel your Order?");
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ourDatabase.open();
                ourDatabase.deleteAllDataReviewYourOrder();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Order Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}

private void addOrder(final String desc, final String price, final String quantity) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_registerpatient";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());


                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (!error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Order Added.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();                            

                        } else {

                            // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                            // message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "add_order");
            params.put("desc", desc);
            params.put("price", price);
            params.put("quantity", quantity);



            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
```

}

I Have two button in my xml file save and cancel button.

reviewyourorder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/greenboard_background" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_your_order_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="@string/review_your_order"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="35sp"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_your_order_quantity_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/review_your_order_tv"
    android:text="@string/quantity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_your_order_description_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/review_your_order_quantity_tv"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/review_your_order_quantity_tv"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/ryo_description"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_your_order_price_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="@string/item_price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_width="543dp"
    android:layout_height="695dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/review_your_order_quantity_tv"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_button"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/review_your_order_listview"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/save_button"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

And here are my textviews which serve as my items inside my custom listview.

reviewyourorder_items.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tablenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/table_no"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemquantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tablenumber"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:text="@string/item_quantity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemdesc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/itemprice"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemprice"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/item_desc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/itemquantity"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemquantity"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
    android:text="@string/item_price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: What do you mean "store on a string"? You have an adapter, just loop over its elements

Comment: As you are using 'ReviewYourOrderNames' array for your order, so if any order removed track it using position or order Id and on final button click iterate your order names and check for order cancellation. 
You will have final order list.

Comment: I am just new in android programming so I still don't know and understand a lot, what i'm trying to do is get all data in listview and send to another activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will helpful for you,

```
int itemsCount = myList.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
     View view = myList.getChildAt(i);
     String itemquantity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemquantity)).getText().toString();
     String itemdesc = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemdesc)).getText().toString();
     String itemprice = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemprice)).getText().toString();
     addOrder(itemdesc,itemprice,itemquantity);
}
```

Comment: can I put this inside the save button? how can I get all the text that I got from the listview and display it?

Comment: I had modified the code. Copy and paste the code inside save button click

Comment: Thank you very much for this. @Sabari

Comment: I have another problem but from a different android project can you try to help me on this too? If you can thank you very much in advance but not it's alright because you already helped me, I just want to try if you can help me again. Here is the link of the problem that I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280761/sqliteexception-no-such-tableitemtable-while-compiling-select-id-from-ite @Sabari

Comment: I hope you got solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280761/sqliteexception-no-such-tableitemtable-while-compiling-select-id-from-ite